# ignore newline for finding a needle in haystack and preserve the text positions

Tags: java, regex, indexof

I'm trying to 'wrap around' a search, basically ignoring \n when using ether indexOf or regex Pattern. I can't just remove all newline chars as then the indexes found would be wrong.

For example:

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("dog").matcher("cat\n do\ng cow");
matcher.find();
int start = matcher.start();
int end = matcher.end();
System.out.println("Start: "+start+" End: "+end);
```

Should output:

```
Start: 5 End: 9
```

If I remove the newlines,

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("dog").matcher("cat\n do\ng cow".replaceAll("\n",""));
```

Then the indexes would be messed up:

```
Start: 4 End: 7
```

Note: I'm also going to be using more complex regex than I used in the example.

I'm implementing the find function in a text editor and am trying create an 'wrap around' option.
Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by ignore them? You say that you can't remove them because the indexes would be wrong, but if you do indexOf it will count the newline chars and you wouldn't be ignoring them. Show desired input and output please.

Comment: Additionally, please show what you are trying (via code) so people can try to guide you into a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to take search keyword and prepare it by interjecting optional line break after every character before you search in the hey-stack. Consider this code:

```
String needle = "dog";
String regex = needle.replaceAll("(.(?!$))", "$1\n?"); // inserts line breaks
// regex now becomes "d\n?o\n?g"
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = p.matcher("cat do\ng cow");
if (matcher.find()) {
    int start = matcher.start();
    int end = matcher.end();
    System.out.println("Start: "+start+" End: "+end);
}
else
    System.err.println("No match available");
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Start: 4 End: 8
```

BTW your expected output 5 and 9 doesn't seem correct to me.

Comment: Looks good for simple strings, but what about more complex regex searches? Sorry there was a typo in code

Comment: Please provide some examples of `more complex regex searches`. As I understand you are trying to find a needle in haystack by ignoring newline characters in between (at least that's what the question title said).

Answer (score 0):

```
myString.replaceAll("\n","");
```

try this one

Comment: That would **replace** the newlines, completely removing them from the string. Do so messes up the indexes.